# Touch scroll on Air for Android in Adobe Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, scroll, touch, movieclip

I'm trying to make a touch-based scrolling `MovieClip` with many buttons.  I want that button to move according to the movieclip's `mouseDown` or `mouseUp` events.  I hope someone can help me with this problem.

```
var maxY:Number = 725;
var minY:Number = 350;
var _startY:Number;
var _startMouseY:Number;
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);

function mouseDownHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    _startY = davies.y;
    _startY = toa.y;
    _startMouseY = mouseY;
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stage_mouseMoveHandler, false, 0, true);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_mouseUpHandler, false, 0, true);
}

function stage_mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var offsetY:Number = mouseY - _startMouseY;
    background_scroll_product.y = Math.max(Math.min(maxY, _startY + offsetY), minY);
    davies.y = Math.max(Math.min(maxY, _startY + offsetY), minY);
    toa.y = Math.max(Math.min(maxY, _startY + offsetY), minY);
}

function stage_mouseUpHandler(event:MouseEvent):void {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, stage_mouseMoveHandler);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stage_mouseUpHandler);
}
```

Before and after scroll :

[image][image]

Comment: What's the expected and the actual outcome?

Comment: I want move that davies button, toa button and many button scrolling like a movieclip, the code i shared only scrolling a movieclip, if i group that button to movieclip, i can't push the button to run on another frame. Sorry my english is not good, and i hope you can help me, thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

**1:** Try replacing `Math.max(Math.min(maxY, _startY + offsetY), minY);` with the following:

```
clamp(mouseY - _startY + offsetY, minY, maxY);

function clamp(original:Number, low:Number, high:Number):Number {
    return (original > high) ? high : (original < low) ? low : original;
}
```

**2:** Move all of your content into a single container.  It's easier to move a one object, rather than moving many objects.

*Many Objects:*

```
0:MainTimeline
    0:background_scroll_product //.y += offsetY;
    1:davies                    //.y += offsetY;
    2:toa                       //.y += offsetY;
    ...
```

*One Object:*

```
0:MainTimeline
    0:container //.y += offsetY;
        0:background_scroll_product
        1:davies
        2:toa
        ...
```

## Demonstration

Below is code that you can drop into a new project and it will compile with a working scrolling container.  Please be mindful that others will likely need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) like this when you ask questions.

```
var background_scroll_product, davies, toa;
demoSetup();

/* ^^^ Omit this if you already have these objects defined ^^^ */

// Create a container for our content.
var container:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(container);

// Put the content inside the container.
container.addChild(background_scroll_product);
container.addChild(davies);
container.addChild(toa);

// setup the min based on the size of the contents.
var loc:Object = {
    "max":50,
    "min":stage.stageHeight - container.height
};

addEventListener("mouseDown", mouseHandler);

function mouseHandler(e:Event):void {
    switch (e.type) {
        case "mouseDown":
            loc.start = mouseY;
            loc.container = container.y;
            addEventListener("mouseUp", mouseHandler);
            addEventListener("mouseMove", mouseHandler);
            break;
        case "mouseUp":
            removeEventListener("mouseUp", mouseHandler)
            removeEventListener("mouseMove", mouseHandler);
            break;
        case "mouseMove":
            // Scroll the container.
            container.y = clamp(mouseY - loc.start + loc.container, loc.min, loc.max);
            break;
    }
}

function clamp(original:Number, low:Number, high:Number):Number {
    return (original > high) ? high : (original < low) ? low : original;
}

function demoSetup():void {
    // This sets up a facsimile of the project, to create a Minimal, and Verifiable example.
    var bg:Sprite = new Sprite();
    bg.graphics.beginFill(0xA1A1A1);
    bg.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
    bg.graphics.endFill();
    addChild(bg);

    background_scroll_product = new Shape();
    background_scroll_product.graphics.beginFill(0xf0e3e5);
    background_scroll_product.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 250, 750);
    background_scroll_product.graphics.endFill();

    davies = new Shape();
    davies.graphics.beginFill(0x243066);
    davies.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 400);
    davies.graphics.endFill();
    davies.x = davies.y = 25;

    toa = new Shape();
    toa.graphics.beginFill(0xdc3734);
    toa.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    toa.graphics.endFill();
    toa.x = 25;
    toa.y = 525;
}
```

---

## Response to FLA

I highly recommend you do not work with scenes, specifically because they create dirty states that are not imminently decipherable.  In fact, as you appear to be working towards a mobile app, you should definitely consider using a full-fledge UI framework such as [FeathersUI](https://feathersui.com/).  Regardless...

**Lingering Container**

The `Timeline` tries to treat each frame as a unique state for the program.  You can visually build a UI this way, but it is clunky.  Furthermore, as you've discovered, when you mix [WYSIWYG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) with functional programming, there are things that the Flash UI was never aware of and never "cleans up".  You manually added `addChild(container)`, and so you're also expected to manually `removeChild(container)`.  You could place that inside your listener function for the back button.

**Container hovering over Titlebar**

Consider your Main Menu heiarchy:

```
0: instance15 (Shape)
1: button_back (SimpleButton)
2: instance16 (StaticText)
3: container (Sprite)
```

As you can see, layers `0` through `2` are your top menu objects.  Moving `container` behind the menu is as simple as calling [`addChildAt()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChildAt()), and setting the second argument to the `0` index.

```
addChildAt(container, 0);
```

**Last Images are clipped**

The reason for this is that your content is not positioned at `y:0`.  If you want to fix that, either move the content to start at `y:0`, or add the offset of your first graphic to the min value...

```
"min":this.loaderInfo.height - container.height - davies.y
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have tried and still have problems about the container, such as:
1. I can not put the image above the scroll as the frame and the scroll move over the frame.

2. When I scroll the container, the last button nippon does not appear.

3. If I press the back button on the product, the scroll container is not lost and still found in the Scane Menu

You can see in the following link:
[https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B366CR2EpFQNN29LU2MtRW1GRjQ]

[https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B366CR2EpFQNNExSV2wwZnh1N2M]

I really hope your help to fix the problem.

Comment: Sory that link have problem, can find on here ; 1).
 [https://www.dropbox.com/s/p9sthqrwor500k7/Product.fla?dl=0]    2). [https://www.dropbox.com/s/6b5ydkgaj20lk0a/Product.mp4?dl=0]

Comment: Thanks Atriace, i can fix that problems :) and thanks again for your help

Comment: I hope it does! :)  I looked through your scene, and fixed the issues I mentioned above.  I've also supplied the helper functions I used inside of it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/udvxvun93f1by8h/IWayanArthana.fla?dl=0

Comment: Thank you so much Atriace because you helped me very well, I want to learn more from you about the action script 3, can I send email or whatapp to contact you? I hope you can help me when I'm confused and frustrated with the another script :)

Comment: Sure! You can reach me on Skype as "Atriace"